# How to Export data from 3 tables in one .csv file php

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, export-to-csv

I want to export the data from the 3 tables without joins in one .csv file.
I am trying with joins but i am not getting the result Which i want.

Below are my table structure

[`Playlist`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4851be/1) [`Songs`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b9bd/1) [`Rating`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71ea75/1)

#### CODE

```
$mysql_host = DB_HOST;
$mysql_user = DB_USER;
$mysql_pass = DB_PASSWORD;
$mysql_db = DB_NAME;

$pre = $wpdb->prefix;

$link = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($mysql_db, $link) or die('Could not select database: ' . $mysql_db);

$query = "SELECT plist.*, psong.*, prate.* 
          FROM " . $pre . "foo_playlists As plist 
          LEFT JOIN " . $pre . "foo_songs As psong
          On plist.playlist_name = psong.splaylist_name 
          LEFT JOIN " . $pre . "foo_rating As prate
          On psong.song_id = prate.rsong_id";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$line = "";
$comma = "";

foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
   $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
   $comma = ",";
}
    $line .= "\n";
    $out = $line;
    mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $line = "";
        $comma = "";
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
            $comma = ",";
        }
        $line .= "\n";
        $out.=$line;
    }
    $csv_file_name = 'songs_' . date('Ymd_His') . '.csv'; # CSV FILE NAME WILL BE table_name_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.csv
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $csv_file_name);
    header("Content-Description:File Transfer");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    echo __($out, "foo");

    exit;
```

I got [`this result`](http://jsfiddle.net/deemi/xY92T/1/) with I want this [`desired result`](http://jsfiddle.net/deemi/Eeh52/1/)

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain bit more about the csv . you need `Table 1` `Table 2` as header and data beneath those ? means you need styled CSV and that's why you tag CSS . right?

Comment: without table structure and desired output, we can not help. you can look for [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: without table structure how can we find the issue? add on http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: ok i give you my DB structure till than wait

Comment: @diEcho Now check my question .... and thanx for the nice tool

Comment: @deemi I see no relation between `playlist` and `song`. How are you able to determine which song belongs to which playlist?

Comment: yes and also there is a relation with songs and rating

Comment: @deemi I get that, but on which key? Normally you would have something like `playlistID` in the `songs` table?

Comment: it is on "splaylist_name"

Comment: where does other columns data of row 3 & 4 comes?

Comment: Tips:table structure must have foreign key references.

Comment: From which table............in songs table there is no foreign key except splaylist_name we save playlist name in this file and match with playlist table and in rating table rsong_id is a foreign key

Comment: but the desired output has redundancy . Please make a clear copy of what you want. forget csv part for a while.

Comment: I just want that i get my three tables data and save into it in csv file but not with joins ...... forget that these tables has a relation with each other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59723/discussion-between-diecho-and-deemi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your problem is that you can't retrieve all the data at the same time in an only MySQL query, as they are not related data. Your problem is just the output, so, you only will have to relate the 3 set of results in an only array. To do that:

- Execute the three querys, and save them in three unrelated arrays.
- Relate them with a key you'll share with all of them.
- Loop over all the arrays assigning values to a main "output" one.

With that, you'll have the array which you can output to get the CSV you want. For the sake of the example, and due I can't write a valid code with your vars and queries, I wrote the following example. It has the 3 different arrays you'll have to get from your database with mock data, but you can grab the idea. Just copy and paste and you'll have the live example:

```
<?php

$playlists  = array(
    array(
        'id'    => 1
    ,   'data'  => 'playlist1'
    )
,   array(
        'id'    => 2
    ,   'data'  => 'playlist2'
    )
,   array(
        'id'    => 3
    ,   'data'  => 'playlist3'
    )
);

$songs  = array(
    array(
        'id'    => 1
    ,   'data'  => 'song1'
    )
,   array(
        'id'    => 2
    ,   'data'  => 'song2'
    )
,   array(
        'id'    => 3
    ,   'data'  => 'song3'
    )
,   array(
        'id'    => 4
    ,   'data'  => 'song4'
    )
,   array(
        'id'    => 5
    ,   'data'  => 'song5'
    )
);
$rates  = array(
    array(
        'id'    => 1
    ,   'data'  => 'rating1'
    )
,   array(
        'id'    => 2
    ,   'data'  => 'rating2'
    )
,   array(
        'id'    => 3
    ,   'data'  => 'rating3'
    )
,   array(
        'id'    => 4
    ,   'data'  => 'rating4'
    )
,   array(
        'id'    => 5
    ,   'data'  => 'rating5'
    )
,   array(
        'id'    => 6
    ,   'data'  => 'rating6'
    )
);

// Count all the arrays and get the bigger:
$num        = 0;
$play_num   = count( $playlists );
$num        = ($play_num > $num) ? $play_num : $num;

$song_num   = count( $songs );
$num        = ($song_num > $num) ? $song_num : $num;

$rate_num   = count( $rates );
$num        = ($rate_num > $num) ? $rate_num : $num;


$output = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i<=$num; $i++ ) {
    $output[]   = array(
        'id_playlist'   => !empty( $playlists[$i]['id'] )   ? $playlists[$i]['id']   : ''
    ,   'data_playlist' => !empty( $playlists[$i]['data'] ) ? $playlists[$i]['data'] : ''
    ,   'id_song'       => !empty( $songs[$i]['id'] )       ? $songs[$i]['id']       : ''
    ,   'data_song'     => !empty( $songs[$i]['data'] )     ? $songs[$i]['data']     : ''
    ,   'id_rate'       => !empty( $rates[$i]['id'] )       ? $rates[$i]['id']       : ''
    ,   'data_rate'     => !empty( $rates[$i]['data'] )     ? $rates[$i]['data']     : ''
    );
}

foreach ( $output as $out ) {
    echo implode( ' - ', $out);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

### Output:

```
1 - playlist1 - 1 - song1 - 1 - rating1
2 - playlist2 - 2 - song2 - 2 - rating2
3 - playlist3 - 3 - song3 - 3 - rating3
  -           - 4 - song4 - 4 - rating4
  -           - 5 - song5 - 5 - rating5
  -           -   -       - 6 - rating6
```

Comment: can you please give me some code help in disscussion

Comment: sure, what do you need?

Comment: that how can i write a query like so i get this result

Comment: i mean queries in array and out put in loop

Comment: Ok, you have to fecth the values from DB. I strongly recommend you NOT TO USE php mysql functions, are they are deprecated. Instead, mysqli or PDO, but anyway, you must write 3 queries, one per set of data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59790/discussion-between-chococroc-and-deemi).